# stripping out unknown values in C#

Tags: c#, split, delimiter

I currently have the following code to get a specific value i need from a string.

```
char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', 'B', 'O', 'B'};
                  string text = input.ToString();
                  string[] words = text.Split(delimiterChars);
```

Unfortunately before the space in the string is unknown characters that are entered in by the user. Is there a wild card that gets all the characters before that space? I was hoping that i could just put a * inside of the first quotation with the space `'* '` but it doesn't seem to like that.

Thanks.

EDIT:

So the string variable is made up of a series of characters inputted by the user then it has BOB and a random integer added to the end. My goal is to retrieve just the number at the end of the string.

An example of a sample string would be "user BOB44"
Sorry for the confusion and thanks again!

Comment: Why would you specify the character `B` twice?  `String.Split(char[])` splits on *any of the characters*, not the string made up of the characters.

Comment: oh i thought that it was splitting it in the order that it was in the string. (sorry i am kind of new at this)

Comment: Can you provide a sample and explain what is to be achieved ?

Comment: Are you trying to get a single substring of the original string, or was your intention to create an array of smaller strings from the original?

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to do. Your code does not make sense, especially not with your current description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to get the number at the end of a string

`/([0-9]*)$/` will capture the last group of sequential numeric characters at the end of a string

In C# (it looks like you're using that language):

```
Regex pattern = new Regex("([0-9]*)$");
MatchCollection matches = pattern.Matches(input);
if (matches.Count > 0) {
    // matches[0] will contain the number
}
```

Comment: how can i get the value of matches (i'm trying to get the int value so i tried 'index = (Convert.ToInt32(matches[1].Value.ToString())-1);'

Comment: Corrected my answer...depending on the method used,  [0] contains the whole string, guess I got mixed up :-(